# How to use solver multiple times for linear programming at once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, solver, vba

I have the following problem!

[image]

I want to perform linear programming to maximize the Objective values (Y) with Solver for all rows 7 to 16 (total 10 times). However, I do not want use Solver 10 times. Is there any automated way to do this? 
For example, for the row 7, the problem can be formulated like this:

```
Max A7
subject to B7>=B2, C7>=B2, D7>=B2,
B7<=B3, C7<=B3, D7<=B3,
B7 + C7 + D7 = 100%
```

Likewise, for the row 8, the problem should be formulated like this:

`Max A8
subject to B8>=B2, C8>=B2, D8>=B2,
B8<=B3, C8<=B3, D8<=B3,
B8 + C8 + D8 = 100%`

As you can see, every row has the same structure of formulation but different cells. Is there any way to achieve this without using Solver like 10 times?
I would very very appreciate it!!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could script this in VBA with a loop. Is that what you are after or something else?

Comment: Thank you very much. Where can I possible find the information about VBA loop?

Comment: Have you considered making cell A5 = sum(A7:A16), then using cell A5 as the objective? But you may find that you hit a constraint limit in the solver... But don't Frontline do an "advanced solver" with more capacity?

Comment: Hi Solar, the sum of the objective functions is not what I want. I think you may have misunderstood. I need to iterate through for each of the cells. They are considered separate linear programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Make sure you add the solver reference in VBA. It's still going to run solver each time but you don't have to keep clicking solver and changing the constraints every time. It will do it all in the background

```
Sub FindMaxYs()
Dim i As Integer
ActiveSheet.Cells(7, 1).Select
For i = 7 To 16
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=ActiveCell, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3)), _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$3"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$2"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$2"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$2"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$3"
    SolverSolve True
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi n.gause, first of all, thank you very much for the code! I am very new to VBA, and do not really know much syntax. May I just ask you what ActiveCell.Offset does?

Comment: @JunJang It's just a way to reference a cell relative to an active cell. For example, say your active cell is B7. If you say ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2), your referring to the cell 1 row down and 2 columns to the right which would be C8.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. May I ask you how you have the line:     SolverAdd CellRef:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$B$3" ?
I mean, this is exactly what I want (it is equivalent to the X1+X2+X3 = 100% constraint), but how does (0,4) come into play?

Comment: @JunJang FYI you can also use it as a reference for non active cells. For example Range("B20").Offset(1, 1).Select would select cell C21.

Comment: @JunJang I added a cell in column E for each row that would sum x1, x2, and x3. I then added a constraint to set that equal to 100.

Comment: Where in the code did you add a cell in column E for each row that sums x1, x2, and x3?

Comment: In VBA go to Tools and select References. Make sure the box for Solver is checked.

Comment: I see. I just did too! So the function runs without an error, but it does not produce the optimal values for the decision variables (X1, X2, and X3) in their respective cells (B7, C7, and D7). I want their values to be printed. For example, if the solution for X1, X2, and X3 given by Solver is 1, 2, and 3, i want B7 = 1, C7 = 2, and D7 = 3

Comment: Hmm not sure why it isn't keeping the answers. You could try adding SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1 at the end of the loop.

Comment: It was because there were already string values 'X1', X2', and 'X3', in the cells! When I removed them, I got the solution values! This is perfect!! Thank you so much n.gause all your help!